Problem with viewing all photos in Lightbox in elementor loop
I tried to find a solution, but I just couldn't do it.
I have a custom post type (CPT) for a photo portfolio. I added categories and tags so that the photos should be sorted. The problem is that I created a elementor loop to display the photos, and everything seems to be sorted fine, but when you click on a photo, it shows up as a single image with no option to browse through them.
I tried to find an answer on forums and various sources, and I also looked for a plugin that could help me with this, but it was all in vain.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/L8oDPGdr.png)

Link: https://penretouch.radyx-dev.com/portfolio/

try to use Loop Carousel widget or adjust lightbox setting. Inside the Loop Carousel widget there is a slides option from that may be you can check and fix the issue.

Thank you for your response! I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I specifically need a loop, as the portfolio is a gallery of works. I also tried to find the Loop Carousel option in the settings to attempt to implement this but couldn't find it. Could you please explain this in more detail? Perhaps the Elementor loop has such an option as well, and it just needs to be enabled. Thank you!

https://snipboard.io/8PDe91.jpg  - Are you able to see this type of settings? Inside The Content tab – Layout
Otherwise you can use this plugin to fulfil your requirements
https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-slider-and-carousel-with-lightbox/

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
